# To have vs Having

Tags: verbs

> (To have/Having) exceeded the company’s annual goals for productivity, all employees in A corporation’s manufacturing division received a bonus.

I don't choose what is the correct answer to it.

In my opinion, both are correct, though there might be a little difference between them in meaning.

I want to know the right answer and the reason.

Answer (score 2):

In the world of programming, there is a simple construction that illustrates this issue:

> IF (**condition**) THEN (**result**)

Applying your example statement:

> IF (exceeded the productivity goals) THEN (employees received bonus)

But, and this is very important, the condition in your statement *has already been fulfilled.*  It happened in the past.  That's a hint: your word choice will have something to do with the past tense and fulfilling a condition.

The solution is the [perfect participle](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-exceed.html), which always reflects the past tense.  The perfect participle of "to have" always has the form "having *verbed*."  In this case, "having exceeded."

The nominal, "to have," is present tense, and therefore cannot be used to indicate the completion of a condition in the past.

Answer (score 0):

> **Having** exceeded the company’s annual goals for productivity, all employees in A corporation’s manufacturing division received a bonus.

*Having* is correct, I'm not sure where you're getting *to have* from.

Comment: Is the reason why 'to have exceeded' is not proper that it is just so ambiguous, if written there, as to interpret the sentence in two ways and cannot fix the time line as to whether it is implying the future perfect event or the present perfect event ?

Comment: *To have X'd* is used to refer to the *concept* of having done the verb. So, for example, *to have loved* refers to the concept of having loved in the past. This, effectively, turns the clause into your subject (I'm sure a learned grammatician will have a better explanation of the concept, but this shortcut will do for now). As such, breaking down the sentence beginning with *to have exceeded...* gets you *subject, main clause*. That, of course, is nonsense. Meanwhile, *having done X* is a subordinate clause, and the *subordinate clause, main clause* construction is fine.

Answer (score 0):

To add some light here. For this kind of statements, the infinitive "to have" is to show purpose, a goal, a desire, whereas the participle "having" is to show possession of something. In this case, the correct answer is "having"

Source: Manhattan GMAT.